# MySQL Query leaves server cpu usage at 80%

Tags: mysql, sql, cpu

I have the following query which is optimized, yet leaves the servers cpu usage at 80% every time it is run. Explain shows that all tables are using correct indexes and minimum number of rows are being scanned. So I have no idea what could be causing this query to kill the server. Would appreciate any help.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    c.id,
    c.sName AS sCompany,
    IF(
      u.isActive = 1
      AND c.bActive = 1,
      'yes',
      'no'
    ) AS bActive,
    COUNT(t1.id) AS nDownloads,
    (
      -- samples received
      SELECT
        COUNT(id)
      FROM tblSample
      WHERE nUserID = u.id
    ) AS nRequests,
    COUNT(t3.id) AS nClicks,
    COUNT(t2.id) AS nImpressions,
    COUNT(li.id) AS nActiveConnections
FROM tblUser u
LEFT JOIN tblCompany c
    ON c.id = u.nCompanyID
LEFT JOIN tblLink li
    ON (
        li.nToObjectID = c.id
        AND li.nFromObjectID != 0
        AND li.sType = 'company'
        AND li.sStatus = 'active'
    )
-- DOWNLOADS
LEFT JOIN tblTracker t1
    ON (
        t1.nUserID = u.id
        AND t1.sClass = 'Media'
        AND t1.sMethod IN ('download', 'image')
        AND t1.sAction = 'download'
    )
LEFT JOIN tblMedia m1
    ON m1.id = t1.nID
-- IMPRESSIONS
LEFT JOIN tblTracker t2
    ON (
        t2.nUserID = u.id
        AND t2.sClass = 'Media'
        AND t2.sMethod = 'imageThumbnail'
        AND t2.sAction = 'impression'
    )
LEFT JOIN tblMedia m2
    ON m2.id = t2.nID
-- PRODUCTS VIEWS
LEFT JOIN tblTracker t3
    ON (
        t3.nUserID = u.id
        AND t3.sClass = 'Product'
        AND t3.sMethod = 'view'
        AND t3.sAction = 'view'
    )
LEFT JOIN tblMedia m3
    ON m3.id = t3.nID
WHERE c.sType = 'media'
GROUP BY c.sName;
```

Img:

[image: Explain plan]

Comment: Transform table t1, t2, t3 instead of LEFT JOIN with subquery to retrieve COUNT, so if cardinality of other remaining tables allow you, remove the distinct. At the end, add indexes

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "leaves server cpu usage at 80%?" Does the query never complete? Does the server keep burning cpu cycles after the query completes? Does this query actually "kill" your MySQL server daemon? Do you have to restart it? You know, this is a complex query.

Comment: @Ollie Jones The query itself times out after a while, but even after it has timed out the cpu usage stays at ±80% for a while longer (few minutes, sometimes longer) before going back to normal. MySQL itself still works and server runs, but simple queries sometimes times out when the server is in this state. To fix this restarting MySQL is usually sufficient.

Comment: It's likely that your web server program timed out and left the query still running. It's not hard to believe that a query of this complexity could run for tens of minutes or more.  `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` issued to the server will reveal this situation.

Comment: You are right Ollie, the program has timed out, but when I run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` it shows that the query is still running. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Anyone have some more help they can offer please? Still struggling to get to the bottom of this issue ;(